# Screenshot DirectX FullScreen Game

Tags: c#

There are many questions on Stackoverflow which raise the similar issue but none has a satisfactory answer.

I am creating an open source application Captura - https://github.com/MathewSachin/Captura in C# and WPF. It can capture Specific Windows or Entire Desktop quite well.
But, when it comes to Direct X full screen games or those made with OpenGL just a Blank image is obtained.

I tried both System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen and BitBlt using User32 and Gdi32 but oth didn't work

Please note that I want to do this in C# and not C++. I want to take Screenshot and not Video

Please don't tell me about the Gdi32 or System.Drawing ways which I already know

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/7279345/43846 - "When a Direct3D device enters fullscreen mode, it's granted exclusive access to the video card.  From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - "when a Direct3D object assumes exclusive mode, all devices other than the one that went full-screen are placed in lost state.""

Comment: Is there no way to capture a full screen Direct3d window

Comment: But I have seen softwares (a list is available on Wikipedia) which can capture full screen games. How do they do it???

Comment: By hooking the renderer mostly... Using the SDK. 

For a C# example of that: 

https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook/tree/master/Capture

Details here:
http://spazzarama.com/2011/03/14/c-screen-capture-and-overlays-for-direct3d-9-10-and-11-using-api-hooks/

Comment: Thank you Richard, I will look into that project soon

Comment: I've verified that the Desktop Duplication API works for some new games.