# How to get game images when they are not currently active window

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-capture, world-of-warcraft

I want to get the game images of world of Warcraft when it's in an inactive window or minimized state.I try to use Win32 API to capture game images, The results were as follows:I can capture normal GUI software images, but can not get game images, only obtained a black image, whether there is a way to achieve. Thank you for your answer : )

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the core code you are using to capture the image, otherwise we can only make guesses. What happens if you run the game in windowed mode rather than fullscreen? You may find that you need to capture the actual graphics stream rather than a Win API screen capture. Here is an answer with more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279345/1270000 You may need to use a special library for this task.